# How to install a certificate to personal store without password?

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, netsh

I am kind of new to certificates and all that stuff.

I have a web application that sends a https request by iframe (it has to be https due to the application itself is also https) to a .NET application running on the client which has an HttpListener listening on https://localhost:[port] so the client app can receive a "do something now" from a browser click.

When I install the client app, I install the *.crt file to the Root-Store and bind it to our port:

```
X509Certificate2 certificateFromCrtFile = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(crtPath));
X509Store rootStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
rootStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
rootStore.Add(certificateFromCrtFile);
rootStore.Close();

string crtThumbprint = certificateFromCrtFile.Thumbprint;
string netshParams = string.Format("http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:[port] certhash={0} appid={{{1}}}", crtThumbprint, Guid.NewGuid());
Utilities.StartProcess("netsh.exe", Environment.SystemDirectory, netshParams, true, true);
```

Now, before that, I have to install the certificate also in the personal store because my "server" in that case is the HttpListener on the same client.

Okay, so I could do it the following way:

```
X509Certificate2 certificateFromPfxFile = new X509Certificate2(pfxPath, "pwd");
X509Store personalStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
personalStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
personalStore.Add(certificateFromPfxFile);
personalStore.Close();
```

In this case I have to write the *.pfx password in clear text in code.
And if I understood correctly, with this password you can easily get the private key, right?

Answer (score 0):

When storing in PFX the private key is encrypted with your password. So when you attempt to install it to a personal store to indicate your ownership of this certificate, you have to present the password. That's mandate.

The trusted root authority is different, as you don't own the certificates. You just install the crt files to say that you trust whoever owns them.